# Textcolor of editable combobox unwanted hover

Tags: combobox, hover, javafx-8

I have an application that contains some comboboxes and one of them is editable.
The textcolor of each comboboxes selected element should be the same. When all comboboxes are non-editable everything is fine, but as soon as one is set to editable its selected item has a different color.
Now the mysterious part begins...
When I hover above the editable combobox the elements color gets the correct color and when I move the mouse outside the combobox it again gets the previous color.
I have no clue how this behavior can happen considering that I haven't even built in any hover-effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use any styling / CSS? Can you provide a small sample?

Comment: can't reproduce (8u60) - colors look fine. Might misunderstand the problem, though: the color I compare is the selected (blueish) background if the text in the editable box is selected vs. the selected background of a selected element in the dropdown

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give you an SSCCE, because I can't reproduce that behavior either

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set the color by using an event on the editable combobox.

```
combobox.setOnAction(event -> combobox.getEditor().setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red"));
```

I'm not quite happy with that solution, but for now its ok.
I will take a closer look on that one when I have more time.